# PHP suddenly started to fail at executing shell commands

Tags: php, linux, shell, apache2

We've got a web server set up running your basic Apache2/PHP 7.2 that's been running fine for at least a month now until this morning when just about every shell command started to fail with errors like this

> PHP Warning:  shell_exec(): Unable to execute 'zip -r -j '/domains/domain.com/public_html/tmp/140dd1f0-6b3f-11e8-84cd-1206bb36a2db/images.zip' '/domains/domain.com/public_html/tmp/140dd1f0-6b3f-11e8-84cd-1206bb36a2db'/*' in /domains/domains.com/public_html/ajax/userquotes/downloadquoterequestimages.php on line 142, referer: ...

And even the Imagick extension was having issues processing images:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ImagickException: FailedToExecuteCommand `'gs' -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r72x72'  '-sOutputFile=/tmp/magick-8882jXzj7ATO9YoA%d' '-f/tmp/magick-8882W_l5stP6rIRq' '-f/tmp/magick-8882B61J5TQj6Fkh'' (-1) @ error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/462 in /domains/domain.com/public_html/ajax/uploadimage.php:125\nStack trace:\n#0 /domains/domain.com/public_html/ajax/uploadimage.php(125): Imagick->__construct('/domains/doma...')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /domains/domain.com/public_html/ajax/uploadimage.php on line 125, referer: ...

This is a moderately used server that sees constant use, and these errors we're happening all at the same time. RAM, Swap, and storage space are all normal and no where near capacity.

I could also run the commands that were failing directly on the server without any problems, and then when I ran `service apache2 restart`, the server restarted normally and everything just started working.

I wish I could have debugged further but since this is a production server I needed a quick fix. Would building PHP from source instead of from a repo decrease the chances of that type of stability issue?

- Linux: Debian GNU/Linux buster/sid
- PHP: 7.2.2-1+0~20180205160612.18+jessie~1.gbpb78b58
- Apache: Apache/2.4.29

Comment: There doesn't look like any actual error message to follow up here. Can you run the zip command in any form at the console? Perhaps the `PATH` has changed, and your two commands that do not specify a fully-qualified directory are no longer found.

Comment: @halfer yeah I was able to run all of the commands, including the zip command, that were failing directly on the server without any issues, only PHP seemed to suddenly be having the issue

Comment: Looks like ghostscript isn't installed? Can you type gs into the terminal? Does anything turn up?

Comment: or it could be permissions if the commands are installed

Comment: @delboy1978uk `gs` gives me output starting with `GPL Ghostscript 9.22`, as I said, all commands directly were working, it was just PHP before the restart having problems

Comment: You could also write a one-line PHP file to execute `zip` or `gs` in a web context, to see what problems it is having (i.e. try calling the script from a browser). My first step would be to qualify those paths (do `which zip`) on the console to see what the full path is.

Comment: @delboy1978uk they were working fine up until about 10:20, then they all started failing, and then apache2 was restarted and they continued working again like nothing happened

Comment: @halfer the piece of the site that use the commands have no problems after the reboot. Sadly I didn't have time to test the server since we needed it working, and the apache2 restart got it all working and we haven seen the same errors since

Comment: I suspect you will have to wait until the problem resurfaces, or rebuild the server before it does. The evidence is likely already gone, but you could check Apache error logs, `dmesg` and `syslogs`.

Comment: @halfer that's what I also feared, and why I asked if anyone's experienced an issue like this in the past, but you keep editing that part out for some reason :)

Comment: The main part I've edited out is to remove the urgency, since [we discourage it here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569). From a technical writing perspective also I tend to remove "has anyone seen this before", since an answer of "yes" is not very useful! Explicit questions are good here ("Would building PHP from source instead of from a repo" is an excellent question).

Comment: And my answer to that question is no, I don't think compiling from source is inherently more stable. What you could do is use a devops approach to be able to swap out parts of your system quickly e.g. rebuild with Ansible/Chef/Puppet, or use images with Docker. Would any of that be possible in your infrastructure?

Comment: @halfer I see, though the question certainly didn't ask for an urgent answer, but was referring to why I cannot test the issue any longer due to past reasons

Comment: Can you take a look at the logs route I suggested earlier? The evidence of the crash may not be fully gone.

Comment: @halfer maybe, I've been looking into potentially setting up a second web server for redundancy purposes anyway and using haproxy infront of them, similar to how we already have our DB servers for the same type of reason, it may be time to do that since our traffic continues to increase and downtime will be worse and worse soon

Comment: @halfer also those messages were from the apache2 log, as it never really "crashed" there wasn't a stack trace, just a whole ton of messages about how the `exec` commands we're failing and nothing more

Comment: OK, fair enough. Maybe look into more of a devops route then, so your servers are essentially throw-away and can be rebuilt/restored at the touch of a button. You can arrange your frontend proxy to flip from one server to another to make the transition seamless (I use Traefik for this, as it supports hot config reloading).

Comment: @halfer yeah I've had awesome results with haproxy myself, since it constantly checks for uptime and can switch automatically. Plus having the servers be redundant I'd be able to stop traffic to the bad one an actually investigate, so we will eventually be going that route for sure

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, specifically with Imagick.

Turned out it was running out of RAM even though memory usage didn't indicate it was getting almost full.
Added more RAM and everything worked great again.